# Finding the matrix representation of a linear transformation $ T: P_{3} \to \text{M}_{2 \times 2} $.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations

Define a function $ T: P_{3} \to \text{M}_{2 \times 2} $ by
$$
  T \! \left( a_{0} + a_{1} x + a_{2} x^{2} + a_{3} x^{3} \right)
= \begin{pmatrix} a_{3} & a_{0} \\ a_{2} & a_{1} \end{pmatrix}.
$$
I know how to show that $ T $ is a linear transformation, i.e.,
$$
T(\vec{u} + k \cdot \vec{v}) = T(\vec{u}) + k \cdot T(\vec{v}).
$$
I also know how to show that $ T $ is an isomorphism (one-to-one and onto), but how do I find the matrix representation of $ T $ with respect to the standard bases of $ P_{3} $ and $ \text{M}_{2 \times 2} $?

Comment: By linearity it suffices to check what $T$ does to the basis elements, how about calculating $T(1), T(x),T(x^2),T(x^3)$ and writing it as a linear combination of those? ($T(a_0+a_1x+\dots)=a_0T(1)+a_1T(x)+\dots$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both vector spaces $P_3$ and $M_{2\times2}$ are of dimension $4$. Their standard bases are respectively
$$
\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}\text{ and }\mathcal{B}:=\{e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22}\},
$$
where $e_{ij}$ is defined to be the matrix with entry $(i,j)$ equal to $1$ and other entries equal to $0$.

The matrix representing $T$ wrt the given bases will be
$$
A_T:=
\begin{pmatrix}
T(1) & T(x) & T(x^2) & T(x^3)
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $T(\cdot)$ is a column vector containing the coordinates of the image of $\cdot$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}$.

For example, since
$$
T(1)=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
we have $T(1)=e_{12}$ and so the first column of $A_T$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Note that the order is important.